# как запихнуть все города Украины в option value="город"

Tags: php, javascript

есть такой код

```html
<input name="city" type="text" list="city">
<datalist id="city">
  <option value="Afghanistan">
  <option value="Albania">
  <option value="Algeria">
  <option value="Andorra">
  <option value="Angola">
</datalist>
```

возможно както запихнуть все города украины в value? И как это можно сделать, посколько их очень много? может както php кодом или js или есть какойто сервис

Comment: Полтысячи городов вполне можно и прописать, почему нет.

Comment: Вот тут https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/ua-cities/blob/master/ua-cities.xml парнишка даже xml сделал... скачивай себе, и через пхп-скрипт вставляй.

Comment: Но список далеко не полный. И часть городов переименовали. Так что нужно его дорабатывать.

Comment: а как вывести ети города на странице .php

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php $cities = array('сюда список городов');?>
<input name="city" type="text" list="city">
<datalist id="city">
<?php
    foreach($cities as $city){
        echo '<option value="'.$city.'">';
    }
?>
</datalist>
```

Comment: это я сам догадался, но где мне взять весь список городов через "город","город"

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B

Comment: я имел в виду как сделать что бы города были через запитую и в лапках для того что бы их пихнуть в array

Comment: @BedOmar гхм. Заходишь на страницу википедии, выделяешь все города мышкой, CTRL+C, вставляешь в любой редактор умеющий регулярные выражения(например notepad++) и вуаля